# Scroll in TailwindCss

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, tailwind-css

I have a problem with horozontal scroll in tailwind css (not scroll):

```
<div class="flex  items-center mb-10 overflow-x-auto  flex-none carousel pr-10 
            opacity-at-end  mt-16 flex-row-reverse">
  <?php $tags = $data->tags; ?> @foreach ($tags as $tag)
  <a class=" flex-none">
  </a>
  <a class="active bg-white tertiary-color fs-18 fw-400 radius rounded-[30px] 
            pt-4 pb-3 px-5 min-h-[44px] text-center ml-5 flex-none">
    {{ $tag->name }}
  </a> @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent element must either have a set `width` or `max-width` in order for [overflow to work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#description). You can use [tailwind's max width utility class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-width) to add a `max-width` to the parent element as follows:

```
<div class="max-w-md">
  <div class="flex items-center mb-10 overflow-x-auto flex-none carousel pr-10 opacity-at-end mt-16 flex-row-reverse">
    <?php $tags = $data->tags; ?> 
      @foreach ($tags as $tag)
        <a class=" flex-none"></a>
        <a class="active bg-white tertiary-color fs-18 fw-400 radius rounded-[30px] pt-4 pb-3 px-5 min-h-[44px] text-center ml-5 flex-none">
          {{ $tag->name }}
        </a>
      @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now its ok.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `overflow-x-scroll` instead of `overflow-x-auto` and make the width somewhat smaller so that you can see the scroll behavior with 2-3 items only.

Below is the code you can check,

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="carousel opacity-at-end mx-auto mb-10 mt-16 flex w-1/2 flex-none flex-row-reverse items-center overflow-x-scroll bg-slate-300 p-4 pr-10">
  <a class="flex-none"> </a>
  <a class="active tertiary-color fs-18 fw-400 radius ml-5 min-h-[44px] flex-none rounded-[30px] bg-slate-400 px-5 pt-4 pb-3 text-center"> $tag->name </a>

  <a class="flex-none"> </a>
  <a class="active tertiary-color fs-18 fw-400 radius ml-5 min-h-[44px] flex-none rounded-[30px] bg-slate-400 px-5 pt-4 pb-3 text-center"> $tag->name </a>

  <a class="flex-none"> </a>
  <a class="active tertiary-color fs-18 fw-400 radius ml-5 min-h-[44px] flex-none rounded-[30px] bg-slate-400 px-5 pt-4 pb-3 text-center"> $tag->name </a>

  <a class="flex-none"> </a>
  <a class="active tertiary-color fs-18 fw-400 radius ml-5 min-h-[44px] flex-none rounded-[30px] bg-slate-400 px-5 pt-4 pb-3 text-center"> $tag->name </a>

  <a class="flex-none"> </a>
  <a class="active tertiary-color fs-18 fw-400 radius ml-5 min-h-[44px] flex-none rounded-[30px] bg-slate-400 px-5 pt-4 pb-3 text-center"> $tag->name </a> a
</div>
```

> I had added 5-6 tags manually instead of for loop. Check in full view